# Convex optimization and in python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, finance, cvxopt

I use excel to minimize a variable and I started using `cvxopt` recently. I am trying to figure out how to minimize a value given two constraints. I have two returns data frame and taking the weights `w1` and `w2`multiplying with the returns and subtracting them. I am finding to minimize the sharpe ratio for the difference of the returns by changing the weights. The constraints here is sum of `w1 = 1` and `sum of w2= 1`

In Excel I use `solver` add in and add constraints `$S$4 = 1` and `$s$5= 1`. I am trying to figure out how to do that in python `cvxopt`. Below is the code I have written for `cvxopt` in creating an efficient frontier.  I would really appreciate any help.

`'import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import cvxopt as opt
     from cvxopt import blas, solvers
    import pandas as pd'`

`

```
def random_portfolio(returns1, returns2):

#Returns the mean and standard deviation of returns for a random portfolio

p1 = np.asmatrix(np.nanmean(returns1, axis=1))
w1 = np.asmatrix(rand_weights(returns1.shape[0]))
mu1 = w 1* p1.T




p2 = np.asmatrix(np.nanmean(returns2, axis=1))
w2 = np.asmatrix(rand_weights(returns2.shape[0]))
mu2 = w 1* p1.T



final = mu1- mu2

mean_ret = mean(final)
voltality = std(final)
sharpe = mean_ret/voltality
n = len(returns1)

G = -opt.matrix(np.eye(n))   # negative n x n identity matrix
h = opt.matrix(0.0, (n ,1))
A = opt.matrix(1.0, (1, n))
b = opt.matrix(1.0)

portfolios = solvers.qp(-sharpe, G, h, A, b)['x'] 
returns = [blas.dot(mu, x) for x in portfolios]
risks = [np.sqrt(blas.dot(x, C*x)) for x in portfolios]

return mean_ret, voltality, sharpe
```

`

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you've written?

Comment: I am not able to assign weights to the constraints

Comment: (1) Direct formulation of the Max Sharp ratio problem is not a QP but a general NLP (it includes a division in the objective). Unfortunately it is non-convex. (2) There is a convex QP reformulation possible (see [link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/08/portfolio-optimization-maximize-sharpe.html))